# Is it possible to attach/mirror a balance to a Bank Account? xero

Tags: xero-api

Is it possible to attach a balance to a Bank Account?

Our product has a bank balance and we process payments that have to be sent back to Xero. I don't understand how to best present our bank balance in Xero or even if it makes sense to do this.

Currently I automatically create an expense account using the API and associate all payments we create in Xero with that. This isn't ideal because we'd like to show the current balance of funds the customer has in our product. Also, the account the user has with us isn't really an expense account it's more of a bank account.

When I create a bank account in Xero, I can't figure out how to associate an existing balance. Any guidance on best practices here would be appreciated.

Is it possible to attach a balance to a Bank Account? Our clients have a balance of funds with us very similar to a bank balance. How can I make that balance show up in Xero and have that account be used for Payments I create using only the API?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the conversion balance for a bank account using the Setup endpoint:

https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api-guides/conversions

That will let you provide the initial balance via the API; the balance from that point is maintained via requests against the BankTransactions endpoint with the appropriate types:

https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/types#BankTransactionTypes